# Visual Studio Code debugger isn't working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Trying to Debug I screw the settings and now I can debug or reset the debug settings, not even uninstalling the program works.
This is what the debug panel looks like

[image: This is what the debug panel looks like]

Comment: then delete the settings.json files (global and workspace)

Answer (score 0):

For debugging python code using the "DEBUG" function in VS Code, please check the following:

1. "Python" extension can be used. The debugging function of python in VS Code is provided by the "Python" extension.
2. Select the python environment in the lower left corner of VS Code. Please make sure that python has been installed and can be used and select the required python environment in VS Code.
3. Configure the "launch.json" file:

> ```
> {
>         // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
>         // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
>         // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
>         "version": "0.2.0",
>         "configurations": [
>             {
>                 "name": "Python: Current File",
>                 "type": "python",
>                 "request": "launch",
>                 "program": "${file}",
>                 "console": "internalConsole",
>                 
>                 },
>         
>         ]
>     }
> ```

Debug: Click F5:

[image]

Reference: [Python Debug in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).